# errors received when trying to set hyperlinks

Tags: php, html

I am trying to set each image name as a hyperlink. But problem is I am receiving 3 errors, 2 are undefined erros and the other one is expecting 1 parameter.

Current code which is not working:

```
    <table id="tableqanda" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <?php
        
function imageName( $imgitem ) {
    return htmlspecialchars($imgitem); //432
}

        
          foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
        echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
        
        if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
            echo '&nbsp;';
        } else {
    echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">'; //line 456
    echo implode('</li>\n<li></a><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">', imageName($arrImageFile[$key]) ); //line 457
    echo '</li></ul></a>';
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Errors received:

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... on line 432

Notice: Undefined variable: imgitem in ... on line 456

Notice: Undefined variable: imgitem in ... on line 457

---

#### Formatted Code:

```
<table id="tableqanda" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <?php
                function imageName( $imgitem ) {
                    return htmlspecialchars($imgitem); //432
                }
                foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
                    echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
                    echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
                    if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
                        echo '&nbsp;';
                    } else {
                        echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">'; //line 456
                        echo implode('</li>\n<li></a><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">', imageName($arrImageFile[$key]) ); //line 457
                        echo '</li></ul></a>';
                    }
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**`var_dump` results:**

From the var_dump specified the results are below:

```
array(2) { 
  [72]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(16) "Lighthouse_4.jpg" 
    [1]=> string(12) "Tulips_3.jpg" 
  } 
  [73]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(16) "Hydrangeas_3.jpg" 
  } 
}
int(73)
```

**UPDATE:**

With Praveen's code I am getting an error stating:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare imageName() (previously declared in ...:451) in ... on line 451`

Below is code:

```
<table id="tableqanda" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
  //line 451          <?php function imageName( $imgitem ) { return htmlspecialchars($imgitem);
            } foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) { echo '
            <tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL; echo '
                <td width="11%" class="imagetd">'; function imageName( $imgitem ) { return htmlspecialchars($imgitem);
                    function getImgLink ( $imgKey ) { return $imgKey[0]; if (empty($arrImageFile[$key]))
                    { echo '&nbsp;'; } else { echo '
                    <ul class="qandaul">
                        <li>
                            <a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . getImgLink($arrImageFile($key)) . ']"
                            target="_blank">'; echo implode('</li>\n
                        <li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . getImgLink($arrImageFile($key)) . ']"
                            target="_blank">', imageName($arrImageFile[$key]) ); echo '</li>
                    </ul>
                    </a>'; } echo '</td>'; } } echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL; } ?></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you are passing this query string `[' . $imgitem . ']`

Comment: `var_dump($arrImageFile)` and post the print here. And where `$arrImageFile` defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There are many errors!!!

1. Where have you defined `$imgitem`?
2. Why are you `implode`ing a string?
3. Why are you closing the function prematurely, and using the variables there in the code out of the function?
4. Where is the `$arrImageFile` defined?
5. Finally, **What are you trying to do?**

#### Other errors...

```
function imageName( $imgitem ) {
    return htmlspecialchars($imgitem); //432
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// You are closing the function here, hence the $imgitem's scope //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


          foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
        echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';

        if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
            echo '&nbsp;';
        } else {
    echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">'; //line 456
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The $imgitem's variable is not accessible here //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    echo implode('</li>\n<li></a><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">', imageName($arrImageFile[$key]) ); //line 457
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Why are you trying to implode something like this? Not a right syntax! //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    echo '</li></ul></a>';
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
```

---

#### Update

```
<table id="tableqanda" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
    <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <?php
                function imageName( $imgitem ) {
                    return htmlspecialchars($imgitem); //432
                }
----------------^
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// You are closing the function here, hence the $imgitem's scope //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
                    echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL;
                    echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
                    if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
                        echo '&nbsp;';
                    } else {
                        echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">'; //line 456
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
/////////////////////////////////////
// Where have you defined $imgitem //
/////////////////////////////////////

                        echo implode('</li>\n<li></a><a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . $imgitem . ']" target="_blank">', imageName($arrImageFile[$key]) ); //line 457
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
/////////////////////////////////////
// Where have you defined $imgitem //
/////////////////////////////////////

                        echo '</li></ul></a>';
                    }
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

Based on the output of `var_dump`, I feel that you need to add another function to get the links of the image, as it is always present in the `0`th index.

```
function getImgLink ( $imgKey )
{
    return $imgKey[0];
}
```

And now, use it this way:

```
<a href="previewImage.php?imgId=[' . getImgLink($arrImageFile($key)) . ']" target="_blank">
```

Comment: `$imgitem` is in function, do I need to define it as `var $imgitem = '';` before using it in the function? I wanted to include the </li>\n<li> so that each image name is in a bullet point, do I not need implode for this? question 3 is because Im learning how to use the function, `$arrImageFile` is an array storing image names retrieved from the db

Comment: You are ending the function prematurely! That function is just one line. Get it?

Comment: I understand what you mean, end the function after the table column. I will start the function before the table column as well. Shall I remove the implode? is it needed?

Comment: @user1881090 I have edited the answer. Now check where your mistake is.

Comment: to answer your question 5 btw, I am trying to set each image name as a hyperlink

Comment: Can you update your question, by posting the output of `var_dump($arrImageFile, $key)`?

Comment: You need to add another function. Lemme update it in my answer.

Comment: I included an update, please have a look, I am getting a fatal error

Comment: @user1881090 Remove that function for now. Guess you have screwed up your code totally. :(

Comment: Did you mean just remove the extra function you stated? because I get same error when doing this. Or do you mean remove both functions?

Comment: No no... Comment out the function on line **451**. And remove the function calls of the same.

Comment: Ok I have commented the line 451 function, now it gives me same error but this time in 454, for the other function which you mentioned I should include, so shall I comment that out as well then post what I have got at moment?

Comment: Dude! LoL. What are you doing? Upload the set of files and send it to me. Will do something... :)

Comment: HAve you got an email address? I will send files to you by email, do you want me to set the code back from when question started?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23355/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-user1881090)

Comment: @user1881090 Buddy, need the DB Dump!

Comment: db data just sent via email

Comment: How are you finding it? Is it going ok?

Comment: Oh dear, I apologize for that. Im more of an oracle developer than a web developer but trying to learn it slowly. Let me just say I really appreciate you helping me buddy :)

Comment: Hey no issues buddy, just challenging myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the square brackets enclosing `[' . $imgitem . ']`. Square brackets are not valid query string char

Another thing, why use `implode`?

Comment: I wanted to include the `</li>\n<li>` so that each image name is in a bullet point, do I not need implode for this?

Comment: It is still giving me same errors, the reason it is in square brackets is because a table row can have multiple images, so I thought that will class it as an array. Do I need an implode or shall I just remove it?

Comment: I tried solution before but having problems, included update in question